# Passing parameters to stored procedure EF6 (MapToStoredProcedures)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have an entity which contains two similar properties, `AttributeValue (byte[])` and `DecryptedAttributeValue (string)`. `DecryptedAttributeValue` just stores a string which will then be encrypted and saved in `AttributeValue`. **I do not want `DecryptedAttributeValue` to be saved in my database.**

I am trying to use code-first to call a SPROC on save opeartions, take in the all the values along with the `DecryptedAttributeValue`, encrypt it and save it in the AttributeValue column. However I am having a lot of issues trying to do this. One error is as follows:

> A parameter binding to the property 'DecryptedAttributeValue' was not
>   found on the modification function 'SubjectAttributeValue_Insert'.
>   Ensure that the parameter is valid for this modification operation and
>   that it is not database generated.

**My entity**

```
public class SubjectAttributeValue
{
   ..... // properties removed for simplification

    public int SubjectAttributeValueId { get; set; }
    public byte[] AttributeValue { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string DecryptedAttributeValue { get; set; }    
}
```

**My DbContext**

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<SubjectAttributeValue>()
            .MapToStoredProcedures(
                s => { s.Insert(i => i.Parameter(p => p.DecryptedAttributeValue, "DecryptedAttributeValue")); }
            );
    }
```

**My SPROC (again other entities removed for simplification, this is not a 1 column table)**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SubjectAttributeValue_Insert]
    @DecryptedAttributeValue [nvarchar](255)
AS
BEGIN
    OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY xx_SymmetricKey
    DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE xx_Cert

    INSERT [dbo].[SubjectAttributeValues]([AttributeValue])
    VALUES (EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('GBAR_Cert'),@DecryptedAttributeValue))

    CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY xx_Cert 

    ... // removed for simplification

END
```